# Incompatibility between CXF and WebSphere JRE

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, cxf, jboss7.x

I've got a JAX-WS web service compiled against an IBM WebSphere JRE that does not seem to be compatible with the cxf stack that comes preinstalled/configured with JBoss7, but works with WebSphere/Axis2.  I am not sure why I am seeing this incompatibility as I am not using any Axis2 specific classes (am only using javax.ws classes), but none the less, I get class incompatibility issues.

My class has no direct dependence on Axis2, which is why I was expecting that the service would work find with cxf, but apparently not.  I am only using `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext` and `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext`.

Just to be on the safe side, I've gone through all my pacakged jar files and didn't find javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext anywhere.  Which is good, since it belongs to the JRE.  Which leads me to believe that there is an incompatibility between my the javax.xml.ws provided by my JRE (IBM JRE) and the CXF stack.

Consequently, I figured I would try to run the service against the Axis2 stack, but I have no idea how to install it under JBoss7.

If anyone can help me understand how the incompatibility and/or how to get Axis2 working with JBoss7, I would appreciate it.

Full stack trace:

```
11:39:02,121 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Application {http://www.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/V1.2}LendingSimulationService#{http://www.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/V1.2}calculateBorrowingData has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext incompatible with javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.createFault(JBossWSInvoker.java:234)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:189)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:117)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452) [:6.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314) [:6.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149) [:6.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:118)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:208)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:162)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:184)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:107)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
        at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:138) [jbossws-spi-2.0.0.Beta7.jar:2.0.0.Beta7]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735) [:6.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext incompatible with javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext
        at com.clientservices.lendingsimulation.util.SoapUtil.extractServiceContextFromHeader(SoapUtil.java:43) [classes:]
        at com.clientservices.lendingsimulation.service.LendingSimulationServiceImpl.calculateBorrowingData(LendingSimulationServiceImpl.java:112) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:6.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45) [:6.0]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) [:6.0]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599) [:6.0]
        at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:169)
        ... 33 more
```

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The explaination can be found at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4201

[Alessio Soldano](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=asoldano) explains that within the bean injecting the WebServiceContext

```
@Resource WebServiceContext webServiceContext;
....
webServiceContext.getMessageContext() <--This is MessageContext not SOAPMessageContext.
```

The only place webServiceContext.getMessageContext() is required to return SOAPMessageContext is in a SOAPHandler (configured in handler-chain)

In your code webServiceContext.getMessageContext() returns a MessageContext as implemented by CXF specfic code (org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext).